# Let $f \in C_0(X)$ and $g \in C_0(Y)$. We define $h$ by $h(x,y) := f(x)+g(y)$. If $h \in C_0(X \times Y)$, then $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 0$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $X,Y$ be Hausdorff topological spaces such that $X,Y$ are both not compact. Let $C_0(X)$ be the space of continuous and vanishing at infinity functions on $X$. By vanishing at infinity, we mean for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact set $K \subset X$ such that $\sup_{x\notin K} |f(x)| \le \varepsilon$.

> Let $f \in C_0(X)$ and $g \in C_0(Y)$. We define $h:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ by $h(x,y) := f(x)+g(y)$. Assume that $h \in C_0(X \times Y)$. Then $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: I see no reason to close this question.  I actually find it quite interesting.

Comment: @Ruy. The proposer has provided no work nor attempt. But I didn't vote.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.  The proposer has provided an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n$, there is a compact set $K_n \subseteq X \times Y$ such that $\sup_{(x, y) \notin K_n} |h(x, y)| \le 1/n$. Let $P^X : X \times Y \to X$ be the projection map. Let $X_n := P^X (K_n)$. Then $X_n$ is compact. We pick some $x_n \in X \setminus X_n$. Then $|h(x_n, y)| = |f(x_n)+g(y)| \le 1/n$ for all $y \in Y$. This implies
$$
\forall y \in Y,f(x_n) \to g(y) \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$
This implies $g$ is a constant, so $g \equiv 0$. Similarly, $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Not that it changes much, but don't you mean $f(x_n) \to -g(y)$?

Comment: @Ruy You're right! I meant $f(x_n) \to -g(y)$. Thank you so much!